# Calculating Conditional Probability without knowing individual probabilities

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

I have a case where I know the probability that three annotators will agree with each other pairwise, and I'm trying to find the probability that all three will agree on a yes or no question given that two already agree.

$P(A=B)=0.9$

$P(A=C) = P(B=C) = 0.6$

What I'm trying to calculate is $P(A=B|A=C)$

Where $P(X=Y)$ is the probability that X and Y agree.

My first go at this is $P(A=B|A=C)=\frac{P(A=B)\times P(A=C)}{P(A=C)}=\frac{0.54}{0.6}=0.9$

But that seems wrong. It seems that since if any of them say yes, each of the others is more likely to say yes, so the fact that two said yes should provide me more information than the fact that one said yes, and therefor $P(A=B|A=C) > P(A=B)$

My next thought was to approach this from correlation, since we know all the answers are correlated if they agree with each other more often than not (esp in the case of $A$ and $B$), but I don't know anything about the random variables $A$, $B$, or $C$ themselves, since they're properties of the dataset given to the annotators. In one dataset, it might be 90% yes's, and 10% no's, but in another, it could be reversed. We could treat them as Bernoulli RVs I guess? I don't know if that helps.

I feel like I'm overlooking something basic, but I'm drawing a blank.

Answer (score 2):

Let create a table first:

```
      ------------------------------------------------------
          A          B           C           Probability
      ------------------------------------------------------
          Y          Y           Y               p1
          Y          Y           N               p2
          Y          N           Y               p3
          Y          N           N               p4
          N          Y           Y               p5
          N          Y           N               p6
          N          N           Y               p7
          N          N           N               p8
      ------------------------------------------------------
           Total                                  1
      ------------------------------------------------------
```

P(A=C) = p1+p3+p6+p8 and P(A=B and A=C) = p1+p8.

So P(A=B|A=C) = (p1+p8)/(p1+p3+p6+p8).

What you have is: `P(A=B) = p1+p2+p7+p8 = 0.9,  P(A=C)=p1+p3+p6+p8 = 0.6, P(B=C) = p1+p4+p5+p8=0.6`

So based on the information you provided, it is impossible to get P(A=B|A=C). So you need to get more information.

For the probability that all three will agree on a yes or no question given that two already agree, it is p1+p8, P(two already agree) = 1.

The probelm in $P(A=B|A=C)=\frac{P(A=B)\times P(A=C)}{P(A=C)}=\frac{0.54}{0.6}=0.9$ is you assume that Event A=C and A=B are independent, but in fact they are not.